# Label not working with checkbox - not saves the checked/nonchecked

Tags: php, html, css, smarty

Sliding works perfectly. Just if i check that it doesnt saves option the checked/unchecked. I know that is something wrong  with (  `{if isset($tmp.negotiable) && $tmp.negotiable==1}checked="checked"{/if}`  ).

```
<div class="switch-box col-xs-6 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 no-hor-padding" style="width:50%;">
    <div class="switch-1 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 no-hor-padding">
        {if $pe_settings[$fieldset].use_negotiable==1}
            <input type="checkbox" class="cmn-toggle-1 cmn-toggle-round-1" name="negotiable" id="negotiable" {if isset($tmp.negotiable) && $tmp.negotiable==1}checked="checked"{/if} value="0" />
            <label for="negotiable"></label>
&nbsp;&nbsp;{$pe_settings[$fieldset].lang[$crt_lang].negotiable}
        {/if}
    </div>
</div>
```

If i remove the

```
> <label for="negotiable"></label>
```

it works and saves the options.

JavaScript:

```
<script>
    {literal}

$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#negotiable").click(function() {
    if( $(this).attr('checked') ){
        $("#negotiable").val('0');
        $('#negotiable').removeAttr('checked');
    }else{
        $("#negotiable").val('1');
        $('#negotiable').attr('checked','checked');
    }
    });

});
{/literal}
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried to put a text into the label tag? If you have no label text you can leave it.

Comment: i tried but nothing. If i add this to javascript code?  {if isset($tmp.negotiable) && $tmp.negotiable==1}checked="checked"{/if}

Comment: It's not feasible to use Smarty code in javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a checkbox you should not change the value. A checkbox works like, if the checkbox is checked, then the value is submitted if the checkbox is NOT checked, then the value is NOT submitted.

```
<input type="checkbox" class="cmn-toggle-1 cmn-toggle-round-1" name="negotiable" id="negotiable" {if isset($tmp.negotiable) && $tmp.negotiable==1}checked="checked"{/if} value="1" />
```

Basically, you should set the value of the checkbox to "1"

Comment: I removed from javascript " $("#negotiable").val('0');" and $("#negotiable").val('1');    and  it works porfectly !!!!! Thanks for help!!!